# How do commit allowances work on Area 51?

Tags: discussion, area-51, commitment-phase, commitment, commitment-fulfillment

I have a couple of questions related to the 3 (actual) commitment allowance:

- Is committing to your own proposal assumed, or does it use up one of the committments you're allowed?
- Is there ever a time you are "refunded" a commitment that you can then use to commit to another proposal?  Say, for example, you commit to a site and it goes live (or even to beta).  Things are going great.  Can you then go back and commit to another proposal to help it get launched?
- Is the commitment allowance hard set at 3?

Comment: I was wondering if everyone got 3, or if it was based on rep.

Comment: @Tim: yeah, I'll admit that was an assumption of mine.  Based on other posts this morning I think it is a hard allowance.  I've edited the question to hopefully clear that up!

Comment: It seems only natural to give back a commit "vote" once a site you have committed to is live.

Comment: @googletorp I agree.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is committing to your own proposal assumed, or does it use up one of the committments you're allowed?

No, it is not *assumed* the author of a Proposal is committed to using the site on day one.

> Is there ever a time you are "refunded" a commitment that you can then use to commit to another proposal? Say, for example, you commit to a site and it goes live (or even to beta). Things are going great. Can you then go back and commit to another proposal to help it get launched?

Once a site exits beta, you are free to commit to another site. Even before the site goes to beta, you can un-commit to apply your commitment to other sites. The idea is that you only have three outstanding commitment "tokens" at any one time.

> Is the commitment allowance hard set at 3?

Yes.

**EDIT**: We changed the way this works. Once a proposal enters the beta phase, your commitment "token" is only freed after the site exits beta.

Comment: "The idea is that you only have three outstanding commitment "tokens" at any one time" reminds me of UserVoice. Wow! It's been a long time...

Comment: Shouldn't you still be committed while a site is in beta and only get that commitment slot back once it leaves beta, or has been in beta for X time (e.g. three months)?

Comment: @Gnome: We're looking into measuring "commitment" before you get your token back but it probably wont be anything like three months. Something lighter. Still under discussion.

Comment: I picked three months from the "answer as many questions as I can for at least three months" part of the current commitment definition, but I agree it sounds a bit long at this point.  Probably easier to later reduce instead of lengthen, though.

Answer (score 2):

Some changes happened since [the original answer by Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53735/202747) came, so it's little different now:

> Is committing to your own proposal assumed, or does it use up one of
>   the committments you're allowed?

This is the same as Robert Cartaino wrote.

> Is there ever a time you are "refunded" a commitment that you can then
>   use to commit to another proposal? Say, for example, you commit to a
>   site and it goes live (or even to beta). Things are going great. Can
>   you then go back and commit to another proposal to help it get
>   launched?

You have to fulfill your proposal while it's in beta, usually through asking 10 posts there, but there are alternatives. See details [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103295/202747).

> Is the commitment allowance hard set at 3?

There is sort of an exception to this rule when the proposals gets closed during the commitment phase. It's not fulfilled, but it doesn't count to the three commitment tokens, so you can have four or more commitments temporarily until it is deleted or or is reopened and leaves beta. See details [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53897/202747).