# When does commitment counter reset on Area51?

Tags: support, area-51, commitment-phase

So every user can commit only to 5 sites on Area51. If a site I committed to reaches private beta/public beta/final release, will I be able to use commitment I spent on that site again? Or I can only commit to 5 sites ever?

Comment: To answer your question body, [you get your commitment back](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53709/how-do-commit-allowances-work-on-area-51/53735#53735). However, when you get it back (the question posed in your title), I don't know.

Comment: Isn't it just three commitments and not five?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to Robert](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53709/how-do-commit-allowances-work-on-area-51/53735#53735):

> Once a site exits beta, you are free to commit to another site. Even before the site goes to beta, you can un-commit to apply your commitment to other sites. The idea is that you only have three outstanding commitment "tokens" at any one time.

So the moment it exits beta, your commitment should be freed up for use on another site.

**EDIT**: We changed the way this works. Once a proposal enters the beta phase, your commitment "token" is only freed after the site exits beta.

Comment: Beta means private beta?

Comment: Ok I've read that answer, looks like exact period is undecided at the moment. Fair enough, at least it is getting "refunded".

Comment: Hm? Looks to me like it's refunded the moment the site goes to beta? If it doesn't it might just be a bug, the whole system's still fairly new

Comment: This answer seems to be incorrect. When is the commitment fulfilled before the beta exits?