# When will committments be released in Area 51

Tags: support, area-51, beta-phase

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When does commitment counter reset on Area51?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55505/when-does-commitment-counter-reset-on-area51)

In Area 51 it is only possible to commit for three proposals at the same time. When a proposal goes into Beta, when is the commitment to this proposal released again?

Comment: The question might be identical, but the answer is incorrect. I have commitment fulfilled tags on sites that are still in beta. In fact, the commitment was release before it came out of private beta. However, the behaviour seems inconsistent. On the faq, I have found somewhere that 10 questions or answers fulfil the commitment.  However, on one commitment I have 13 and have not been released. What is going on?